# Does authlogic give session location information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

Let's say, for example, that my website has the following locations that a user can visit:
/dashboard
/users/settings

I want the ability to detect that the user is viewing any of those pages.

Does authlogic have this build in? are there any alternatives?

I am using Google Analytics as a long-term (and better) solution.  However, for admin stats, i'd like to show what part of a website that a particular user is browsing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, authlogic doesn't have this functionality built in because it has nothing to do with authentication.  You'll need to do this yourself, which is very simple by using a `before_filter` in your controller(s) to record which action the user is visiting.

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with it.